# Resetting SendKeys message

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I created a program what will type a text for me automatically by using SendKeys command. When I press start button the text will be typed as it should, and when I press start button the text will stop from typing. The typing is done by using an interval timer which will decide when to start typing and have a brief space between typing 2 lines.

The problem is that when I start typing and type part of the message then press stop before program can type the entire message then start typing again, the message will continue to type from where it stopped. For example I want to type the message "123456789". I start typing then program types "1234" then press stop so program wont type no more. Then when I press start again program should start typing from 1, but instead my program types "56789".

How to reset the line when I stop, then start again? I tried to make the message as a "message" variable which is reset when I press stop button but it doesn't work.

This is how I set to type every interval tick:

```
    private void Space(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbRandomLine.Checked || tickCount < lbMessage.Items.Count)
        {
            var index = cbRandomLine.Checked ? randomLine : tickCount;
            var item = lbMessage.Items[index].ToString();

            SendKeys.Send(item.Substring(currentChar++, 1));

            if (currentChar == item.Length)
            {
                SendKeys.Send("{enter}");
                tmrSpace.Enabled = false;
                currentChar = 0;
            }
        }

        tmrSpace.Interval = random.Next(10, 100);
    }

    private void Delay(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (delayCount == 0)
        {
            tmrDelay.Stop();
            tmrInterval.Start();
            lblDelay.Text = "Typing...";
        }
        else lblDelay.Text = "Typing in: " + delayCount;

        delayCount--;
    }

    // METHODS

    private void WhenStarted()
    {
        tickCount = 0;
        delayCount = 2;
        lbMessage.Enabled = false;
        txtMessage.Enabled = false;
        if (cbDelay.Checked)
        {
            lblDelay.Text = "Typing...";
            tmrInterval.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            lblDelay.Text = "Typing in: 3";
            tmrDelay.Enabled = true;
        }
        cbPause.Enabled = false;
        cbDelay.Enabled = false;
        cbRandomLine.Enabled = false;
        btnStart.Enabled = false;
        btnStop.Enabled = true;
        btnStop.Focus();
    }

    private void WhenStopped()
    {
        lblDelay.Text = string.Empty;
        whenStart = false;
        tickCount = 0;
        txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        lbMessage.Enabled = true;
        txtMessage.Enabled = true;
        cbPause.Enabled = true;
        cbDelay.Enabled = true;
        cbRandomLine.Enabled = true;
        btnStart.Enabled = true;
        btnStop.Enabled = false;
        btnStart.Focus();
        tmrDelay.Enabled = false;
        tmrInterval.Enabled = false;
        tmrSpace.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void SetInterval()
    {
        if (nudPlusMinus.Value == 0)
        {
            tmrInterval.Interval = int.Parse(nudInterval.Value.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            tmrInterval.Interval = random.Next(int.Parse(nudInterval.Value.ToString()) - int.Parse(nudPlusMinus.Value.ToString()), int.Parse(nudInterval.Value.ToString()) + int.Parse(nudPlusMinus.Value.ToString()));
        }
    }

    private void ListBoxContentCheck()
    {
        if (lbMessage.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reset the `currentChar` variable.

Comment: well there's a quick 50 :)